# A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, double-click, listboxitem

In my class, I've written Double click event for ListBoxItem. When clicked on the entry of the listBox, it should return that specific entry only. But in my case, though I clicked on single entry, all the entries are returned and "InvalidCastException" occures. so, how should I change to get single entry.

Here is Double click event code:

```
private void ListBoxItem_DoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Submit clicked Entry
        Harvest_TimeSheetEntry entryToPost = (Harvest_TimeSheetEntry)sender;

            if (!entryToPost.isSynced)
            {
                //Check if something is selected in selectedProjectItem For that item
             if (entryToPost.ProjectNameBinding == "Select Project")
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Select a Project for the Entry");
                else
                    Globals._globalController.harvestManager.postHarvestEntry(entryToPost);
            }
            else
            {
                //Already synced.. Make a noise or something
                MessageBox.Show("Already Synced;TODO Play a Sound Instead");
            }
    }

In xml:

<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Margin="0,131,0,59" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" ListBoxItem.MouseDoubleClick="ListBoxItem_DoubleClick"/>
```

Comment: What line is throwing the invalid cast exception?  are you sure the sender is a Harvest_TimeSheetEntry?  Base on your explanation I don't think that it is.

Comment: You can use ListBox.SelectedItem to get the clicked item inside double click event

Comment: This line shows exception- Harvest_TimeSheetEntry entryToPost = (Harvest_TimeSheetEntry)sender;

Answer (score 4):

ListBox implicitly wraps its items into `ListBoxItem`. Try to cast `sender` to `ListBoxItem` then take its `Content` property

Comment: I tried casting in this way- ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)sender;

Comment: But I want that item in Harvest_TimeSheetEntry because further functionality depends on it.

Comment: Call Content property of ListBoxItem. Added this to answer

Comment: I tried with 3 different ways but still showing same exception.

Comment: ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)sender;
Harvest_TimeSheetEntry entryToPost=(Harvest_TimeSheetEntry)item.Content;

Comment: Harvest_TimeSheetEntry entryToPost = (Harvest_TimeSheetEntry)((ListBoxItem)sender).Content;

Comment: Harvest_TimeSheetEntry entryToPost = (Harvest_TimeSheetEntry)sender.Content;

Answer (score 0):

Try to use as Operator instead of Direct casting and include null check before further process

Answer (score 0):

Finally, It works.

```
private void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //Submit clicked Entry
        try
        {
            ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)sender;
            Harvest_TimeSheetEntry entryToPost = (Harvest_TimeSheetEntry)item.Content;

            if (!entryToPost.isSynced)
            {
                //Check if something is selected in selectedProjectItem For that item
                if (entryToPost.ProjectNameBinding == "Select Project")
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Select a Project for the Entry");
                else
                    Globals._globalController.harvestManager.postHarvestEntry(entryToPost);
            }
            else
            {
                //Already synced.. Make a noise or something
                MessageBox.Show("Already Synced;TODO Play a Sound Instead");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
     }
```